# How to pin OS package versions in Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Scenario**

For obvious reasons I believe that every package installed in a Docker image should have their version nailed down.
That's why in our `Dockerfile` we always enforce the OS package manager to install a specific version of a package.
For example:

```
FROM node:6.10.0

RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get -y install nginx=1.6.2-5+deb8u6 \
      && apt-get -y install supervisor=3.0r1-1+deb8u1
```

**Problem**

The upstream repository has changed and the `nginx=1.6.2-5+deb8u6` package is now invalid.

I'm not sure what brings about this change but I think it has something to do with distros going out of their support-cycle or that old packages are removed/moved somewhere else.

**Question**

How do I nail the exact version of OS-leveled packages without running into this problem?

*Note*: I know these 2 options will work but I want to know if there's an easier way out:

1. Make a custom base image
2. Download the binaries and `COPY` them into the Docker image

Comment: Any new ideas here?  Looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this qualifies as an "easier" way, but you could host the specific packages on a server (e.g., [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), [S3](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/s3/)).  You would then have the Dockerfile connect to this location and use the packages from there.

This would allow you to avoid creating a custom base image and you would not have to manually download the packages.